# How to think about $y(x)$ in differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, soft-question, partial-derivative

In a problem I am asked to compute the solution to the differential equation

$2+\sin(x+y)+\sin(x+y)y'(x)=0$.

I found it already confusing that $y$ is written as a variable, but the derivative is written as a function. This is just lazy notation as far as I understand.

Now in another problem I am asked to find all functions $f(x)$ such that

$[y(x)]^2\cos(x)+y(x)f(x)y'(x)=0$

is an exact differential equation.

I now want to proceed by checking for which $f(x)$ the condition

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y(x)]^2\cos(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}y(x)f(x)$

is satisfied. But how do I compute the derivative in this case? If I consider $y$ just an arbitrary variable, the derivative is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}yf(x)=yf'(x)$. But isn't $y(x)$ a function of $x$, hence $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y(x)f(x)=y'(x)f(x)+y(x)f'(x)$?

This last part is what confuses me the most. Any clarification would be very appreciated.

Comment: Consider $z(x)=x+y(x)$. Then the equation can be seen to already be exact.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: So the first problem is just for illustration. In the second you can just divide out $y$ to get a linear or separable DE. Discuss also the case $y=0$. If no modification is allowed, set $z=y^2$ to get a little simplification.

Comment: $2+\sin(x+y)+\sin(x+y)y'(x)=0$ then $2+\sin(x+y)(1+y'(x))=0$ then $2+\sin(x+y)(x+y(x))'=0$ change the variable so $u=x+y$ then $2+u'\sin u=0$

Comment: Wherever you see $y$, simply substitute $y(x)$.  Alright, just a bit lazy of the original authors, but unambiguous and easily fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining whether a 1st order differential equation is exact, the first order of business is to rewrite it in the form
$$(*) \qquad M(x,y) + N(x,y) y' = 0
$$
Here's the key point: $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are each given as functions of $2$ independent variables. In your case, where $M(x,y) = y^2 \cos(x)$ and $N(x,y) = y f(x)$, you should certainly know how to proceed with the calculation of $\partial M/\partial y$ and $\partial M / \partial y$ in the usual fashion when $x,y$ are two independent variables.

Now, back to the equation $(*)$, if you want to decipher the meaning of that equation then you can pick a function name $y=\phi(x)$ and write its derivative as $y'=\phi'(x)$ and then you can simply use those equations for $y$ and $y'$ to substitute into equation $(*)$, to get this meaning:
$$M(x,\phi(x)) + N(x, \phi(x)) \phi'(x) = 0
$$
Finally, regarding the process of actually solving the equation, I'll just throw in what you probably already know: when you are done applying the method of exact equations to $(*)$, what you will end up with is an implicit equation of the general form $P(x,y)=0$; you can, if you like and if it is possible, solve for the final function $y=\phi(x)$, although you are also free to leave the solution in implicit form.

---

One last point regarding the issue you raise about "lazy notation". You aren't wrong about that point. Nonetheless, what people learn, and what we expect students to learn, is how to tell in what context $x$ and $y$ are a pair of independent variables, and in what context $x$ is independent and $y$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

To explore the equation as exact differential equation, write it as
$$
\cos(x)y^2\,dx+f(x)y\,dy=0
$$
where for the moment both $x$ and $y$ are independent free variables. This equation describes a direction at each point in the plane, and solutions are curves that are tangent to the direction lines in every point.

This means that $M(x,y)=\cos(x)y^2$ and $N(x,y)=f(x)y$. Computing the partial derivatives and comparing them should now be straightforward.

Comment: Please read my full post, this is not about how to solve this particular problem but rather a question about notation, thanks.

Comment: Yes, and I wrote on how you have to modify the notation to go from ODE to exact DE. You go back from an equation for a function to the exploration of functions in two variables.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand what you meant.